# Sitecore Rocks Error - The Path is not of a legal form

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sitecore, sitecore-rocks, sitecore8

I am having the error "The path is not of a legal form" when I try to execute a *comandy* over the Sitecore Rocks.

I am using VS2013, Sitecore 8, Windows Server 2012 (on a Virtual Box).

[image]

have you got any idea about what could be happen here?

Thanks for all! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. 
If you have this issue, you need to utilize the "Hard Rock Web Service" data provides as you local provider.  Otherwise you will have this problem.

[image]

I hope this help.

Regards.